# How do I get a number of items in a filtered list?

Tags: angular, pipe, filtering

So, I have a filtering pipe and using it to filter a list of cities to show only those that include a search term.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
        transform(value: any, arg: string) {
            var searchTerm = arg ? arg : '';
            searchTerm = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
            if (value == null) return null;
            return value.filter(el => el.City.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1);
        }
    }
```

But the array of cities I have has 5000 items in it, so I use a slicing pipe to show only five of them.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="search" type="text">
  <div>
    <li 
    *ngFor="let city of cities | filter:searchTerm | slice:0:5"
    (click)="PasteCity(city.City)">
      {{ city.City }}
    </li>
  </div>
</form>
```

But there lies a problem. I need to show to the user, how many cities were found, e.g. "5 0f 631 cities are shown".
As far as I tried, `ViewChildren` and indexing the last element of `*ngFor` methods only got me the number of cities shown, not found by filter... But whilst trying to use `ViewChildren` I got an error and quickly scraped this idea

Comment: you should be using a directive instead of a pipe

Comment: I am trying to find a way how, but all the ways of filtering I find are made using pipes, could you explain method you're suggesting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try

```
(cities | filter:searchTerm).length
```

?

Comment: I need to know length before the array goes through slice pipe, so, as I recon, your code would give me 5 or less, and that is not the case

Comment: It worked! I added '{{ (cities | filter:searchTerm)?.length }}' after the <li> elements! Thank you so very much! Kudos